# Как правильно получить ключ массивы по значение?

Tags: php, массивы

Как можно получить все ключи по `session = jutv0undrd4l1eodf4mm4egd5c`? [Код здесь](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b849cbed9b2fe93686bbdf5fc792b077da7531c)

Наш массив

```
$array = [
    "5c0789634134f" => (object)[
        "id" => "5c0789634134f",
        "session" => "jutv0undrd4l1eodf4mm4egd5c"
    ],
    "5c07896482972" => (object)[
        "id" => "5c07896482972",
        "session" => "jutv0undrd4l1eodf4mm4egd5c"
    ],
    "5c07896a5c5f2" => (object)[
        "id" => "5c0789634134f",
        "session" => "bvboak847tnbmhnsehogtct7dr"
    ]
];
```

---

Этот код вернет только первый ключ

```
var_dump(array_search("jutv0undrd4l1eodf4mm4egd5c", array_map(function($user){return $user->session;}, $array)));
```

> string(13) "5c0789634134f"

Как можно получить такой ответ?

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "5c0789634134f"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "5c07896482972"
}
```

Comment: *Для того, чтобы возвратить ключи для всех найденных значений, используйте функцию **array_keys()** с необязательным параметром **search_value.*** http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php

Comment: @Akina спасибо но функция array_keys() возвращает числовые и строковые ключи, содержащиеся в массиве array.

Answer (score 0):

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) Вам поможет

вот пример упрощенный [песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a75a0e9e175d52654bdc0f5ba020f97f43845f29)

```
<?php

function test($var)
{
    return ($var=="5c07896482972");
}

$array = ["5c0789634134f","5c07896482972","5c07896a5c5f2","5c07896482972"]; 
print_r(array_filter($array, "test"));

?>
```

Comment: Спасибо обновил вопрос посмотрите

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам, спасибо всем! [Код здесь](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2fa00229f9f0a0e5e9e062fd783cc320d0644894)

```
<?php

$array = [
    "5c0789634134f" => (object)[
        "id" => "5c0789634134f",
        "session" => "jutv0undrd4l1eodf4mm4egd5c"
    ],
    "5c07896482972" => (object)[
        "id" => "5c07896482972",
        "session" => "jutv0undrd4l1eodf4mm4egd5c"
    ],
    "5c07896a5c5f2" => (object)[
        "id" => "5c0789634134f",
        "session" => "bvboak847tnbmhnsehogtct7dr"
    ]
];
$newarray = [];
foreach(array_keys($array) as $key){ 
    $temp = $array[$key]->session;
    if ($temp == 'jutv0undrd4l1eodf4mm4egd5c'){ 
        $newarray[$key] = $array[$key]; 
    }
}
var_dump($newarray);
```